# Spring Reactive MongoDB not saving document

Tags: spring, mongodb, kotlin, spring-data-mongodb

I'm trying to save a basic document but despite connecting to mongodb successfully... It doesn't seem to want to save.

**Spring logs**

```
2018-10-03 00:17:25.998  INFO 10713 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2018-10-03 00:17:26.049  INFO 10713 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2018-10-03 00:17:26.106  INFO 10713 --- [ctor-http-nio-1] r.ipc.netty.tcp.BlockingNettyContext     : Started HttpServer on /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:8080
2018-10-03 00:17:26.106  INFO 10713 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.web.embedded.netty.NettyWebServer  : Netty started on port(s): 8080
2018-10-03 00:17:26.112  INFO 10713 --- [  restartedMain] c.l.s.ServiceLegalApplicationKt          : Started ServiceLegalApplicationKt in 3.459 seconds (JVM running for 4.201)
2018-10-03 00:17:26.644  INFO 10713 --- [ntLoopGroup-2-2] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:3, serverValue:4}] to localhost:27017
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
spring.data.mongodb.database=legal
spring.data.mongodb.repositories.type=reactive
spring.mongodb.embedded.version=4.0.2
```

**basic interface and class**

```
interface EventRepository: ReactiveMongoRepository<Event, String>

@Document
class Event(id: String, name: String)
```

**trying a simple save function**

```
@Service
class SomeService(val eventRepository: EventRepository)
{
    fun save() = eventRepository.save(Event(UUID.randomUUID().toString(), "hey"))
}
```

Comment: and how did you used value returned by save()  method? with reactiveRepository you have to subscribe to it to see the result, if nobody needs this result, what's the purpose to actually do something?

Comment: oh crap. That's my bad. Completely forgot about the subscription. Thanks for pointing that out @VladMamaev

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
Mono<Event> response = repository.save(Event(UUID.randomUUID().toString(), "hey"));
```

Changes in save method

```
fun save() = eventRepository.save(Event(UUID.randomUUID().toString(), "hey")).subscribe();
```

You have to invoke subscribe() method on Mono reference to see the logs or details.

Comment: But thus I get `Disposable`, how to return `Mono` from function?

Answer (score 0):

To make you stream terminal with `subscribe()` operation and to get the Mono result at the same time - split into two separate operations:

```
Mono<String> myEvent = eventRepository.save(Event(UUID.randomUUID().toString(), "hey"));
myEvent.subscribe();
return myEvent;
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are using ReactiveMongoRepository; you cannot do a .block() as suggested by Mukundan.